# Specific questions about design

Tags: discussion, site-policy, specific-question

I have some confusion whether specific question which are asking about design off-topic or on-topic? Specifically these 2 questions are confusing me

- [Are private extension methods a bad thing to use?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30118/are-private-extension-methods-a-bad-thing-to-use)
- [Designing DAOs that handle composite objects](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30123/how-to-design-daos-that-handle-composite-objects)

I flagged for both to be migrated to Programmers SE as they had design issues. The flags were accepted but the questions were not migrated. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Jamal Does your answer to [this question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/813/specific-questions) apply here? I am having doubts about whether I understood that completely.

Comment: I took Jamal's answer to apply to these. But perhaps we need more discussion on what is and isn't on-topic. (Will think about it...)

Comment: @AseemBansal: Winston Ewert has covered that now.  On an unrelated note, your "@" didn't seem to alert me.  Darn.

Comment: @Jamal So I should consider questions which have working code whose working OP understands as on-topic even if they are asking specific questions? Is that the gist of the last question or did I miss anything?

Comment: @AseemBansal: That would entirely depend on the questions, then.  If they're all off-topic (and no general review is requested), the entire post is off-topic.  For that second question, though, I wouldn't say it's entirely on-topic (at least the way it's worded).  Specifically, it seems more opinion-based as the OP wants to know which is "better."  A better request would be about which is more practical for this particular type of problem.  But, "better" is less to type, so there's that.

Comment: @Jamal By specific questions I meant specific questions like "which of these X codes is better in Y situation" where X are working codes and Y can be design, style, a particular application area etc.

Comment: @AseemBansal: In that case, I'd allow it.

Comment: @Jamal Thanks. I needed to be clear about that. Next time I go checking questions I'll remember that.

Comment: @AseemBansal: No problem.  Until the FAQ is updated (unless it already has been), feel free to reference that question to other users.

Comment: Just how does this become policy or not?  @Jamal has been citing his answer as the new official policy in comments on the main site, but has there been some vote or other community decision to back that up?

Comment: @itsbruce [Thie question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/813/specific-questions) was asked on the meta for community consensus. There was noone against that after 4 days. If you think that this policy is wrong feel free to place an answer of your own.

Comment: @itsbruce The voting, I think, is the upvotes to the answers when deciding a new site-policy. I asked [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194812/how-to-properly-decide-on-a-new-site-policy) on main meta. It might be useful for people to have a look at that question's response also.